# multiple queries as an named native query in orm.xml fle

Tags: sql, jpa, orm, mybatis, nativequery

I want to write multiple queries as one named-native-query in orm.xml file. I tried to seperate queries by ; but I have got invalid expression exception. I have tried with / and unfortunately I have got the same exception. How can I do this? -----------

```
 <named-native-query name="action.physicalDelete">
 <query>
   delete
   from table1 a
   where a.id =?1
   ;
   delete
   from table2 b
   where b.id= ?1
   ;
   delete
   from table3 c
   where c.id= ?1
   ;
   delete
   from table4 d
   where d.id= ?1
 </query>
  </named-native-query>
```

Comment: <named-native-query name="physicalDelete">
    <query>delete from table1 a where a.id =?1 ; delete from table2 b where b.id= ?1 ; delete from table3 c where c.id= ?1 ; delete from table4 d where d.id= ?1 </query>
  </named-native-query>

Comment: what is the parameter you are passing as ?1

Comment: @JimMacaulay : it is a String

Comment: Then the issue would be your parameter would be passed without single quotes

Comment: Jim Macaulary ، based on my application business, the parameter is filled by user and I am sure the problem does not refer to the parameter. The problem is that Jpa could not recognize ; or / az a query seperator.